# How can i correctly access the data in my database using room library

Tags: android, android-room

```
List<Game> gamesList = db.gameDao().getAll();
```

I am trying to iterate through the list and make use of the data in the database, the command successfully receives the rows but how can I use the content of each row

Answer (score 1):

You got the List already. now you can loop through and get the data like this

```
for(Game singleGameItem: gameList)
    singleGameItem.memberObj
```